# Java Date getTime function returns negative value

Tags: java, date

I'm converting a String to a date, then converting it integer value to make the comparison between dates easier. Here's my code:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz",Locale.US);
lastModified = "Sun, 02 Oct 2011 18:38:26 GMT";
Date date = format.parse(lastModified);
lastModifiedDate = (int) date.getTime();
```

Then, I printer lastModifiedDate and it was (-974253872), I know it should be the time in milliseconds from Jan 1, 1970, but it's negative value, so what's happening?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`date.getTime()` returns a `long`. If you cast it to `int`, it may become negative due to overflow.

If you change your code to :

```
long lastModifiedDate =  date.getTime();
```

You'll get a positive value - 1317580706000 - which can't fit in an int variable.